# Serialized Form Problems with my Image Upload Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using the following PHP script (pretty much copy-pasted from W3Schools) to store an image passed by POST form:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["imageUpload"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["imageUpload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["imageUpload"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["imageUpload"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["imageUpload"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["imageUpload"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["imageUpload"]["size"] < 500000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["imageUpload"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Error: try again";
  } else {
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"])) {
      echo "Error: a file with that name already exists";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageUpload"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]);
      echo "upload/" . $_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"];
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Error: make sure file is less than 500kb and is a gif/jpg/png";
}
?>
```

I'm using the following jQuery to 'ajax' the form to the server:

```
// AJAX Form
$("#uploadImageForm").submit(function() {
    var url = "imageUpload.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#uploadImageForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data); 
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here is the form's HTML if it's of any help:

```
<div id="uploadImageDialog" title="Upload Image">
        Select the image you wish to upload.
        <form method="post" action="imageUpload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadImageForm" id="uploadImageForm">
            <input type="file" name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
</div>
```

The PHP script works fine when I manually submit the form. However when I submit it with the AJAX I keep getting the "Error: make sure file is less than 500kb and is a gif/jpg/png" message. Of course the file is indeed valid but for some reason it fails one or more of the *if* checks. I suspect it's because the form is serialized. I know what serialization does but I have no clue how/if something needs to be done on the server script to accept serialized data? Or is the problem elsewhere?

Comment: Error: make sure file is less than 500kb and is a gif/jpg/png" message i think error obvious

Comment: @sakir Thanks for trying to help! However if you read my post you will see that I immediately said the **file is valid**. Submitting the file by POSTing the form manually doesn't cause an error. The problem only arises with the AJAX POSTing and is unrelated to the file type or size.

Comment: take a look at this one http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/